# Dudas trigger en SQL-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta SQL-server y sé que hay muchas de las cosas que preguntaré sorprenderán a más de uno, pero a base de prueba y error, explicaciones y ahora preguntas directas intento comprender un poco más todo este mundo.

Tengo un trigger creado en SQL-Server que me funciona, pero tengo ciertas dudas que ahora expondré. El trigger es el siguiente:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[porc_solar]
   ON  [dbo].[TABLA_1]
   for insert
   as
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into calculos
SELECT
'porc_solar' AS metric,
(select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from TABLA_1
 WHERE TAG ='VALOR1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE()),tmdt)/(1440)))
*
100
/
((select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from TABLA_1
 WHERE TAG ='VALOR1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE()),tmdt)/(1440)))
 +
 (select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP) as VALUE
from TABLA_1
 WHERE TAG ='VALOR2'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE()),tmdt)/(1440)))) as VALUE,
 getdate() as time
 
END

GO
```

Como podéis ver, de una forma muy rústica busco hacer una función matemática, a la cual le agrego un nombre y la hora en la que se ha hecho la consulta. Mis dudas/comentarios son:

1. El trigger me salta cada vez que se introduce un nuevo insert en la tabla TABLA_1, pero ésta recibe 14 inserts (1 por cada variable distinta que recoge un dato) en un segundo cada 15min, por lo que me crea 14 filas cuando me valdría con una. Creo que se podría hacer una delimitación poniendo una especie de "where tag = 'Valor1'" para que solo me cree una por vez, pero lo he intentado en la zona de "as" sin resultados positivos. ¿Hay alguna forma de delimitarlo y que salga 1 vez relacionandolo con la sentencia  de insert "where tag = 'Valor1'" en vez de cada insert que le entra?
2. He visto que cada trigger puede tener varias instrucciones Begin-End. Puesto que quiero replicar el trigger que he puesto para otras variables (Valor3, Valor4, etc), ¿sería aconsejable crear nuevos trigger o solo hacer un trigger y hacer una estructura begin 1 end 1, begin 2 end 2, etc?
3. Relacionado con la anterior, cada vez que se active el trigger, querría borrar entradas de las tablas para controlar el tamaño de las mismas. ¿Mismo trigger o distinto?
4. Por último, he visto ejemplos de trigger que terminan con un "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;" justo antes del END. ¿Sería aconsejable ponerlo en cada begin-end? ¿Solo al final de cada trigger? No termino de entender que en algunos casos, o alguna gente sí lo use y otra no.

Muchas gracias de antemano a cualquier comentario que me arroje un poco de luz.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque el escenario que planteas es del todo incompleto, porque no se puede reproducir, ni la sentencia insert, ni la tabla de donde viene...etc.

Y aunque va un poco en contra de la naturaleza del sitio, donde deberías de hacer un hilo por cada pregunta, que puedes enlazar para establecer un mismo contexto.
Me voy a permitir el lujo de responderte, aunque acabe cerrada.

**Pregunta 1**:
El trigger se ejecuta por cada insert, pero puede contener varias filas. Los triggers se manejan con unas pseudo-tablas, llamadas inserted y deleted. No son valores escalares como los tratas.
Si el trigger corresponde con la tabla `tabla_1`, la pseudo-tabla `inserted` tendrá la misma estructura que `tabla_1` y los valores que se están insertando.

Para poder filtrar la operación y solo realizarlo con lo que indicas, puedes hacerlo tal que: (solo está la select)

```
SELECT 'porc_solar' AS metric
     ,
              (
                select top (1)
                       Max(TEP) - Min(TEP)
                       from TABLA_1
                       WHERE TAG = 'VALOR1'
                       group by tag
                              , Floor(DateDiff(MINUTE, DateAdd(day, -1, GetDate()), tmdt) / 1440)
              ) * 100 / 
              (
                (
                                   select top (1)
                                          Max(TEP) - Min(TEP)
                                          from TABLA_1
                                          WHERE TAG = 'VALOR1'
                                          group by tag
                                                 , Floor(
                                          DateDiff(MINUTE, DateAdd(day, -1, GetDate()), tmdt) / 1440)
                                 ) + (
                                       select top (1)
                                              Max(TEP) - Min(TEP) as VALUE
                                              from TABLA_1
                                              WHERE TAG = 'VALOR2'
                                              group by tag
                                                     , Floor(
                                              DateDiff(MINUTE, DateAdd(day, -1, GetDate()), tmdt) / 1440)
                                     ) 
            ) as VALUE
     , GetDate() as time
     FROM INSERTED 
     WHERE TAG = 'Valor1';
```

Por tanto, ante una inserción del tipo `Insert into tabla_1 (col1, col2, tag) values (1,2,'Valor1');`, el mismo se ejecutará con su sentencia insert en la tabla cálculos. Caso de que no sea tag='Valor1' no.

***Pregunta2:***

No tiene sentido. Los triggers son operaciones de conjuntos. Si la sentencia insert se realiza sobre varias filas, el trigger se dispara una vez.
Existen alternativas, que se hacen del tipo cursores, o bucles, pero no son recomendables.
Luego puedes plantear una buena select que tenga en cuenta todas las condiciones, y con una sola sentencia tendrás algo mucho más rápido y mejor.

**Pregunta3:**

Eso de controlar el tamaño es una pregunta muy diferente, con un montón de posibilidades diferentes para un escenario que no has planteado. No tiene mucho sentido borrar una fila y entonces disparar un código de borrado con las penalizaciones que pueda conllevar por el tamaño.
Tal cual lo dices, parece más bien una llamada cada cierto tiempo a un procedimiento que se encargue de realizar los mantenimientos que correspondan.
Los triggers son costosos, para hacer cosas que no son necesarias, en cada operación.

***Pregunta 4:***

La transaccion solo realiza el **rollback** una vez (Puede haber varios commits pero un solo rollback). Esto se hace cuando ocurre un error, bien sea porque algo está mal, o simplemente por la lógica de la aplicación que quieras implementar para que los datos no se persistan.

Lo suyo será que devuelvas un error, implementando un bloque `try catch`, mediante `raiserror` o mediante `throw` y capturas el mismo en el `catch`, y luego haces el `rollback transaction`, siempre y cuando aún este abierta.

Comment: No sabía si hacer 4 hilos por cada pregunta, o agrupar todos para tener resumido este tipo de cuestiones. Sabiendo que es preferible más hilos, desglosaré este hilo en caso de que lo cierren por si tuviera que indagar más en alguna de las preguntas.
La pregunta 1 fue perfecto con la puntualización que me hiciste.
En cuanto a la segunda pregunta, dices que sería mejor incluir todo en un select, quería que el resultado se mostrase con una estructura final de nombre, valor y tiempo en cada operación que quiera hacer. Es decir, si quiero hacer 4 operaciones, tenga 4 filas con su información

Comment: Y tengo que mirar bien cómo borrar los valores anteriores. Había pensado en seleccionar con un `DateAdd(day, -5, GetDate())` para eliminar todo lo anterior a 5 días, pero aún tengo que investigarlo.
@Javi fer2 Cuando dices que los triggers son costosos, ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Recursos del sistema?

Comment: Plantealo de otra manera, Si insertas 10000 filas al día durante 5 días. Cuantas veces va a hacer un trigger la sentencia de delete para dejar solo la info de los últimos 5 días. = 10.000 * 5. Aunque no le toque aplicar nada. Ahora bien. si tienes un procedimiento almacenado, que llamas una vez al día, con un job del agente sql o con una tarea programada, tendrás una sentencia por cada dia = 5

Answer (score 0):

Para delimitar el trigger para que solo se ejecute una vez cuando se inserta una fila con un tag específico, puedes agregar una condición "WHERE" en la sentencia "INSERT" dentro del cuerpo del trigger. Por ejemplo, si solo quieres que se ejecute el trigger para las filas con el tag "Valor1", puedes agregar una sentencia "WHERE tag = 'Valor1'" en la sentencia "INSERT".

Si quieres replicar el mismo cálculo para diferentes variables, puedes crear un solo trigger y utilizar varias estructuras "BEGIN-END" dentro de él para cada variable. Esto te permitiría tener todo el código del trigger en un solo lugar y facilitaría la gestión de las modificaciones.

Si quieres borrar entradas de las tablas para controlar el tamaño de las mismas, puedes hacerlo dentro del mismo trigger utilizando una sentencia "DELETE" dentro de cada estructura "BEGIN-END". Sin embargo, también puedes crear un trigger específico para el borrado de las entradas, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

El uso de "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION" en un trigger depende de tus necesidades específicas. La idea detrás de usar "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION" es cancelar una transacción en caso de que algo salga mal en el código del trigger. Sin embargo, si estás seguro de que tu código es correcto y no hay posibilidad de errores, entonces no es necesario utilizar "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION". Si decides utilizarlo, se recomendaría ponerlo justo antes del "END" del trigger.

Creo que ayudaría mucho si incluyeras la definición de la tabla dbo.TABLA_1 y no solo el código del trigger.